# getchar() doesn't work in C

Tags: c, getchar

I'm using `getchar()` to get a word in C and use switch to know what was the input, but it doesn't wait for input. Can anybody tell me why that is?

and this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Written By A.Rahbari\n");
    float velocity_ratio_of_sun_and_planet ;
    float velocity_ratio_double_gear;
    float N_Annulus;
    float N_Sun;
    float N_Planet;
    float u;
    int x;
    int y;
    int i;
    int g;
    printf("Enter velocity ratio of sun and planet:\n");
    scanf("%f",&velocity_ratio_of_sun_and_planet);
    printf("Enter velocity ratio of double gear:\n");
    scanf("%f",&velocity_ratio_double_gear);
    printf("Enter sun or annulus:");
    g=getchar();
    switch(g)
    {

    case '10' :
        printf("your design is based on annulus\n");
        printf("Enter range of annulus teeth per inch:\n");
        scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
        printf("Enter nember of range step:\n");
        scanf("%d",&i);
        for (N_Annulus=x; N_Annulus<=y; N_Annulus+=i)
        {
            N_Sun = N_Annulus / (velocity_ratio_of_sun_and_planet - 1);
            N_Planet=( N_Annulus - N_Sun )/2;
            u=(N_Sun - floor(fabs(N_Sun)))+(N_Planet - floor(fabs(N_Planet)));
            printf("g");
            if (u == 0)
            {
                printf("\t%d\t\t   %d\t\t %d\t\t\n",N_Annulus,N_Sun,N_Planet);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
         }
         break;

    case 's':

        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Basic rule: if your input is line-based, then use line-based functions.  Look at `fgets`.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `getchar()` does not *wait* because the last `scanf()` leaves a newline (`\n`) into the input buffer due to the last ENTER key press after `scanf()` input.

You need to clean up the buffer before you can call `getchar()` if you expect `getchar()` to *wait* for user input.

Comment: If I could only have penny for every time somebody made this error :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead `g = getchar();` try `scanf("%c",&g);`

Comment: Please elaborate on how this answers the question.